# nightwatchjs with assert calling browser.end() on AssertionError

Tags: node.js, assert, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to check that a table cell on a page contains a number greater than 0.

To achieve this I have to use the node assert package:

```
const assert = require('assert');
```

So first, I get the table cell element text, and in the callback I parse it to an int and use assert to check it's value:

```
...
    .getText("//table[@id='topology-summary-table']/tbody/tr/td[7]", function(el){
        assert(parseInt(el.value) > 0, "Num Executors == 0!");
    }).end()
...
```

The only problem with this is that if assert throws an AssertionError (ie: if the number in the table cell is 0), then the test halts, and `.end()` never gets called, thus leaving the browser process open and hanging around. Not ideal.

I have got around that fact by doing the following:

```
...
    .getText("//table[@id='topology-summary-table']/tbody/tr/td[7]", function(el){
        try {
            assert(parseInt(el.value) > 0, "Num Executors == 0!");
        } catch(e){
            this.end();
            throw e;
        }
    })
...
```

but for some reasons this makes me feel bad. :(

My question is: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nightwatch api actually extends the assert api, so there is no need to `require` it.

Instead, do this:

```
.getText("//table[@id='topology-summary-table']/tbody/tr/td[7]", function(el){
  this.assert.ok(parseInt(el.value) > 0, "Num Workers == 0!");
})
```

Answer provided by beatfactor here: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1002#issuecomment-223240103